# Trouble Updating Field on a Particular Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a record in a particular existing row of data.

```
EX: Existing Output; Team,       Year,   Player,    Position
                     LA Lakers   2016    Jim Bowen
```

Can someone provide me a sample of the code to update 'Position' column

```
Update LAL_Player_Stats
Set POSITION = C 
Where Player = 'Bowen'
```

This returns: (0 row(s) affected)

Comment: If you only want to match on the player surname then look into using `like`.  Example syntax is `WHERE Player like '%Bowen%'`

Comment: 'Jim Bowen' does not equal 'Bowen'

Answer (score 3):

- You may have to try `Player = 'Jim Bowen'`.
- `Position` should not be all caps.
- Also, you need single-quotes on the "C": `Set Position = 'C'`.

Making your final statement:

```
Update LAL_Plater_Stats
Set Position = 'C'
Where Player = 'Jim Bowen'
```

Answer (score 1):

`Update LAL_Player_Stats SET position = 'C' WHERE player = 'Jim Bowen'`

In the future, why not provide us the whole table so we can determine what you're missing when you update a row. It might help us more. :)

Comment: Below is another DB I am creating.                                                                Columns are: Team, Year, Player, Games, POS, SO. I received the same message when attempting to update the POS & SO Fields                             Update NYM_Player_Stats
Set SO = '9'
Where Player like '%Ruggiano%'

Comment: Below is another DB I am creating.                                                                Columns are: Team, Year, Player, Games, POS, SO. I received the same message when attempting to update the POS & SO Fields                             Update NYM_Player_Stats
Set SO = '9'
Where Player like '%Ruggiano%'                                                                    Returns (0 row((s) affected.

Comment: Got it to work - Mistyped the player's name. Thank you.